How to connect to a MYSQL Database in cobol using Gnucobol (Via Dockerfile)
I am working on a prototype for a COBOL application in a container. Now I wanted to connect it to a database and I found ODBC. But it did not work our because I got the following error during docker build:
0.141 /function/YTR93.cob: 36: error: SQLCA: No such file or directory
0.141 /function/YTR93.cob: 36: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier or Literal, expecting .
0.151 /function/YTR93.cob: 34: error: invalid level number 'EXEC'
0.152 cobc: call to cobc_plex_strdup with NULL pointer
0.152 cobc: aborting codegen for /function/YTR92.cob (unknown: unknown)

This is my cobol SQL-Code:
    EXEC SQL
      INCLUDE SQLCA
    END-EXEC.
    EXEC SQL
     CONNECT TO 'MySQL' USER 'admin' IDENTIFIED BY 'ABCDEF'
    END-EXEC.
    EXEC SQL
       SELECT Vorname INTO :host_variable
       FROM table_name
       WHERE condition
     END-EXEC.

This is my Dockerfile:
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
  g++ \
  make \
  cmake \
  unzip \
  wget \
  gnucobol \
  unixodbc \
  unixodbc-dev \
  wget \
  gnupg \
  && wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-ODBC/8.0/mysql-connector-odbc_8.0.29-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb \
  && dpkg -i mysql-connector-odbc_8.0.29-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb || apt-get -f install -y \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /mysql-connector-odbc_*.deb


# Set environment variables for MySQL Database configuration
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=bank1 \
    MYSQL_USER=admin \
    MYSQL_PASSWORD=B:7L1f!r?xP3?8    \
    MYSQL_HOST=database-1.cho40iaoa3pu.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com \
    MYSQL_PORT=3306

# Setup ODBC Driver in odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "[MySQL]\n\
Description=ODBC for MySQL\n\
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8a.so\n\
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8S.so\n\
FileUsage=1\n\
Server=$MYSQL_HOST\n\
User=$MYSQL_USER\n\
Password=$MYSQL_PASSWORD\n\
Database=$MYSQL_DATABASE\n\
Port=$MYSQL_PORT" > /etc/odbcinst.ini

# Interaktive Frontend Einstellungen zurücksetzen
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=dialog

# Compile the cobol programs
RUN cobc -x --free ${FUNCTION_DIR}/YTR93.cob ${FUNCTION_DIR}/YTR92.cob -o ${FUNCTION_DIR}/cobol-program -lsqlca


"call to cobc_plex_strdup with NULL pointer " - Can you please upload the example (full /minimal source to reproduce that) to the gnucobol bug tracker?

In any case you'd likely want to do a multiostate docker file - one for the setup and one that does the compile, see https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/

So you would take the RUN cobc into a Multi-stage build?

Yes, this way the setup doesn't need to be done each time but the part would already be stored in an image, which you then only force-build if the dependencies do change (or you do the apt update also in the second part, if you want to use the most current one every time)

For EXEC anything you need to first preprocess the file, in this case with an EXEC SQL preprocessor. For MySQL I'd suggest to use GixSQL.
This will then convert the EXEC to "pure COBOL" which will then be passed to the COBOL compiler.

I will look into it, thank you. Have you ever worked with GixSQL?

Yes, I did (and have seen it working well in general and have a not resolved bug in a huge application context [see its issue-tracker if you are interested). But I think those details are not really part of the answer to your question, is it? If not please upvote/accept.

I am a little bit confused how to integrate it into my project

... then I suggest to check its README and if you have any issues create a follow-up question on that

Do I get it right: I have to set ENV-Vars in my Dockerfile to pass "://[:port][/dbname][?[opt1=val1]&...]" to COBOL? Or how does COBOL get these informations

This is a total different question to the compile error. I'd suggest to split these question - 1 Q + 1 A. What do you think about keeping this one (potentially with an edit) on "how to compile EXEC SQL in COBOL" and another one for "how to setup GixSQL connections" and potentially others for the docker part?
.... and of course it is always useful to have, for each of those "what did you tried, what does ar least a quick glance on the documentation tell you" together with the relevant example code.

Sorry for the late answer, I was working on some different topics. That is great, thank you so much.

I created a new question btw. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78502839/how-to-setup-gixsql-connections

Can you help with that question too? Thank you so much in advance.
